# Searching in SQLite Database flutter

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

How do I use a TextField widget as a search bar to query results from a local SQLite database asset?

Would there be a better option than using a textfield widget?
Examples would be much appreciated.

edit with code:

```
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Container(
                  height: 70.0,
                  color: Theme.CompanyColors.iBlue,
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Card(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Icon(Icons.search),
                            new Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100.0,
                              child: new TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'Search',
                                  //onChanged:
                                  //onSearchTextChanged,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

This is the code for the searchbar

my database has a table sentences attached with a paragraph_id, so i would want to search through a query like this

```
select * from sentences where title or body = userinput%
```

Comment: How would I incorporate a SQLite query in a method to search through the database and return its results?

Comment: for searching in SQLite you just need to write a SQL query that searches through DB. If you have any example of your database and code, please update your questions. I will answer with an example.

Comment: Edited with code

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using [this plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite). You should create and fill the database ([plugin's docs](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/sqflite/latest/)).

Then, in the search widget, use below example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Database database;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // open the database
    openDatabase('pathToDb', version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      database = db;
      // When creating the db, create the table

    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (database == null) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Container(
                  height: 70.0,
                  child: new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: new Card(
                          child: new Container(
                              child: new Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                            new Icon(Icons.search),
                            new Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100.0,
                              child: new TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Search',
                                    //onSearchTextChanged,
                                  ),
                                  onChanged: (String text) async {
                                    List<Map> res = await database.rawQuery(
                                        "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE title LIKE '%${text}%' OR  body LIKE '%${text}%'");
                                    print(res);
                                  }),
                            )
                          ]))))))
        ]));
  }
}
```

NOTE: If multiple widgets have access to DB, use SQL helpers. read the documents, section "SQL helpers". this example is just for your example.